# C++ error: expected a '{'

Tags: c++

Help!
I'm new to C++...
how can I fix this header file?

```
#pragma once
class MyCls2
{
private:
    int _i, _j;
public:
    MyCls2(int i, int j) : _i(i), 
                            _j(j)
    MyCls2(); // error: expected a '{'
    ~MyCls2(void);
};
```

This is the error in MS VC 2010:

> error: expected a '{'

---

Thanks for the help, I got what I want now:

.h:

```
#pragma once
class MyCls2
{
private:
    int _i, _j;
public:
    MyCls2(int i, int j) ;
    MyCls2();
    ~MyCls2(void);
};
```

.cpp:

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "MyCls2.h"


MyCls2::MyCls2()
{
}

MyCls2::MyCls2(int i, int j) : _i(i), 
    _j(j)
{
}
MyCls2::~MyCls2(void)
{
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the function body in your definition of the `MyCls2` constructor that takes two ints.

```
MyCls2(int i, int j) : _i(i), 
                        _j(j) {}
```

Think of the initializer list as being part of the constructor itself (its definition, not its declaration). You can't have part of a function's definition somewhere, and another part elsewhere.

If you want the initializer list in the header, you need the rest of that definition (the constructor body) in the header too, as above.
If you don't want the definition in the header, don't put the initializer list in the header, put it in the implementation file.

```
//header
  MyCls2(int i, int j);
```

```
// implementation

MyCls2::MyCls2(int i, int j) : _i(i), _j(j)
{
   // constructor body
}
```

Comment: Amazingly fast... thanks...
but it is just the header file, so I assume it should not have a function body?

Comment: No, header files can have inlined function body, and your syntax is an implicitly inlined constructor function.

Comment: @im_chc: if you don't want to define the constructor in the header, you need to put only `MyCls2(int i, int j);`. Put the initilization list in your implementation file, along with the body of the constructor (even if it is empty). But there is nothing wrong with having the constructor body in the header, especially if it is very short.

Comment: so that means in a header file, a function def with an initializer list will be forced to be an inline function?

Comment: Yes/No. Think of the initializer list as being part of the constructor  itself (its definition, not its declaration). You can't have part of a function's definition somewhere, and another part elsewhere. If you want the initializer list in the header, you need the rest of that definition (the constructor body) in the header too. If you don't want the definition in the header, don't put the initializer list in the header, put it in the implementation file.

Comment: @Matt: Thanks, yours should be the right answer to the question

Answer (score 5):

You are providing the constructor definition using initializer lists. So, it needs a `{}` like any other (member) function.

```
MyCls2(int i, int j) : _i(i), 
                       _j(j) {} // Missing the opening and closing braces
```

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
MyCls2(int i, int j) : _i(i), 
                        _j(j)
```

with

```
MyCls2(int i, int j) : _i(i), _j(j) { }
```

The constructor needs a body, even if it's an empty one.

Answer (score 1):

Braces for constructor:

```
MyCls2(int i, int j) : _i(i), 
                            _j(j) {}
```